# Set based solution to extract data from SQL server in comma delimited, ordered lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I need to create an extract file that has a comma delimited string with data from each of 4 different tables and group it by their id.
(This is a simplistic representation of the issue - I am dealing with tens of thousands of unique eid's and millions of rows in table 3 where each eid could have thousands of matching records.)

- Table 1:(one row per id) eid, name, rank
- Table 2: (one row per id) eid, state, calendar
- Table 3: (many row's with the same id) eid, contact name, company
- Table 4:(one row per id) eid, title, code

And I need a an extract that takes the information from each table in a comma delimited format with each person's record in one set and in a specific order - with table 1's information first, then table 2, etc.

```
For instance:
e01,jon jones,1   --from table 1
e01,ca,spring         --from table 2
e01,fred mac, abc     --from table 3
eo1,freddie may, xyz  --from table 3
e01,president,0001    --from table 4
```

My first thought was just to use variables and CONCAT to put the information in XML string for each table and then select that string for each eid using a cursor -- however this creates a separate xml file for each eid and I need all records in one.  When I tried sending the output to a file from SSMS, the result was truncated - I am guessing due to the XML character limitations, but I am not sure.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to better handle this.  Is there a set based solution that I am overlooking?

Thank you

---

Here's the code that I have already:

```
DECLARE @rec1 VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @rec2 VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @rec3 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @rec4 VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FTrec VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @eid INT
DECLARE @newLine AS CHAR(1) = CHAR(10)
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @rID INT


set @count = (select count(*) from tmp_openSDrec)
set @rID = 1

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN

set @eid = (select eid from tmp_openSDrec where rID = @rID)

set @rec1=(
    SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(LayoutVersion as VARCHAR(3)),',',submissionType,',',terYear,',',zzType,',',CAST(terVCCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',
                    CDSCode,',',physicalterName,',',terAddr,',',terCity,',',terState,',',terZip,',',adminContFirstName,',',adminContLastName,',',
                    adminContPhone,',',adminContEmail,',',techContFirstName,',',techContLastName,',',techContPhone,',',techContEmail,',',CAST(numTranscripts as VARCHAR(4))
                    ,',',CAST(carnegieUnitConversionFactor as VARCHAR(6)),',',calendarCY,',',calendarCY1,',',calendarCY2,',',calendarCY3,',',CAST(drgMatchingfieldName as VARCHAR(2)),',',
                    extractDate,',',eor)
    from tmp_openSDrec
    where eid = @eid
    FOR XML Path(''))

SET @rec2=(
    SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(terVCCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',CAST(eid as VARCHAR(20)),',',empNumber,',',firstName,',',lastName
                    ,',',empCity,',',empState,',',empZip,',',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dob,112),',',gender,',',rank,',',hireDate,',',divRank,',',
                    region,',',supConsent,',',eor)
    from tmp_open01rec
    where eid = @eid
    FOR XML Path(''))

SELECT @rec3=(
    select CONCAT(recordID,',',rank,',',terAttended,',',terVCCode,',',terYear,',',term,',',blockSchedule,',',workInProgress,',',
                    CAST(fieldID as VARCHAR(25)),',',fieldName,',',colPrepInd,',',creditsAtmpt,',',creditsEarned,',',fieldrank,',',subjectArea,',',eor,@newLine)
    from tmp_open02rec
    where eid = @eid
    FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @rec4=(
    select CONCAT(recordID,',',language1,',',language2,',',' ',',',' ',',',' ',',',' ',',',eor)
    from tmp_open05rec
    where eid = @eid
    order by recordID
    FOR XML Path(''))

SET @FTrec='FT,*'

    set @result = (select @rec1 + CHAR(10) +  @rec2 + CHAR(10) + @rec3 + @rec4 + CHAR(10) + @FTrec + CHAR(10))
    select @result for XML Path(''), type



    set @count = @count - 1
    set @rID = @rID + 1

END
```

---

I am thinking now that the script will work IF I can get around the XML character limitations.   I have been trying to add a bcp command to the WHILE loop:

```
DECLARE @SQLCmd as VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
set @fileName = 'c:\bcpoutput.txt'
SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp ' + '"SELECT   ' + @result + ' FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE "' + ' queryout '  + @FileName + ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

But I can't seem to get that to work either...
the result is:

```
output
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]
NULL
```

Comment: In SQL Server, I think there will be a Data Transformation Service thing that will do this, although it's been years since I used SQL Server...

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: My first thought would be to push back on sending someone data inthis awkward format. I had to import data like this once and it took a good six months of work to get about 20 differnt files all in this  format into my nice relational database.  However if your dat is going to be consumed by some mainframes, they expect htis format, but try asking for a better format first.

Comment: @Bret, it is called SSIS now

Comment: My  question for you is will the tables all have the same number of columns (as in your simplied example) or will you need the data to have differnt number of columns in differnt lines?

Comment: No - the tables do not all have the same number of columns - each table is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a better solution though.  I scrapped this and went with an ordered Union All instead of assigning all these variables.  I was then able to take this and input to a temp table, and then BCP'd that temp table out to a csv file - and then rinse, wash, repeat for each eid.  Here's my final solution:

```
DECLARE @eID INT
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @rID INT
DECLARE @SQLCmd as VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)

set @count = (select count(*) from tmp_openSDrec)
set @rID = 1 --because eID is sequential and unique in tmp_openSDrec

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN

set @eID = (select eID from tmp_openSDrec where sdID = @rID)

--drop the tmp_opentemp table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tmp_opentemp]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tmp_opentemp]

SELECT field1 into tmp_opentemp
FROM
(

        SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(LayoutVersion as VARCHAR(3)),',',submissionType,',',terYear,',',zzType,',',CAST(terVCCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',
                    CDSCode,',',physicalterName,',',terAddr,',',terCity,',',terState,',',terZip,',',adminContFirstName,',',adminContLastName,',',
                    adminContPhone,',',adminContEmail,',',techContFirstName,',',techContLastName,',',techContPhone,',',techContEmail,',',CAST(numTranscripts as VARCHAR(4))
                    ,',',CAST(carnegieUnitConversionFactor as VARCHAR(6)),',',calendarCY,',',calendarCY1,',',calendarCY2,',',calendarCY3,',',CAST(drgMatchingfieldName as VARCHAR(2)),',',
                    extractDate,',',eor)
        as field1, 1 as sortOrder, recordID
        from tmp_openSDrec
        where eID = @eID
  UNION ALL

        SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(terVCCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',CAST(eid as VARCHAR(20)),',',empNumber,',',firstName,',',lastName
                    ,',',empCity,',',empState,',',empZip,',',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dob,112),',',gender,',',rank,',',hireDate,',',divRank,',',
                    region,',',supConsent,',',eor)
        as field1, 2 as sortOrder, recordID
        from tmp_open01rec
        where eID = @eID
  UNION ALL
    -
        SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',rank,',',terAttended,',',terVCCode,',',terYear,',',term,',',blockSchedule,',',workInProgress,',',
                    CAST(fieldID as VARCHAR(25)),',',fieldName,',',colPrepInd,',',creditsAtmpt,',',creditsEarned,',',fieldrank,',',subjectArea,',',eor)
        as field1, 3 as sortOrder, recordID
        from tmp_open02rec
        where eID = @eID
  UNION ALL

        select CONCAT(recordID,',',language1,',',language2,',',' ',',',' ',',',' ',',',' ',',',eor)
        as field1, 4 as sortOrder, recordID
        from tmp_open05rec
        where eID = @eID

) sq
order by sortOrder, recordID;

SELECT @SQLCmd = 'bcp "select * from [sandbox].dbo.tmp_opentemp" queryout "c:\bcptest.csv" -w -t -T -S && type c:\bcptest.csv >> c:\bcpappendd.csv' ;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;

    set @rID = @rID + 1;

    set @count = @count - 1;



END
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT eid + ',' + x + ',' + y + ',' as results FROM (
    SELECT tblnum, eid, x, y FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS tblnum, eid, name AS x, rank AS y FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS tblnum, eid, state AS x, calendar AS y FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS tblnum, eid, contactname AS x, company AS y FROM table3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 AS tblnum, eid, title AS x, code AS y FROM table4
    ) combined
    ORDER BY eid, tblnum
)
```

Comment: This is good unless he simplified too much and the differnt tables actually have a differnt number of columns